# Send Httpclient POST on successful form submit in Angular 2

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-httpclient

Currently when I submit a form, the HttpClient POST does not execute. However if I add `e.preventDefault()` to the `sendBreakdown()` method, the POST runs successfully. Although when this happens, the form does not submit or run any validation upon the email `<input>` field.

Ultimately I would like to send a `Data[]` and the email address a user enters into the form to my HttpClient POST.

**QUESTION:**

**a)** How can I run an HttpClient POST on (and only) on a successful form submission, without using `e.preventDefault`?

**b)** How can I obtain the email field, and send it along with other data to the POST request?

**finished.component.html**

```
 <form class="form-group-submit">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required  placeholder="Enter your Email Address">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit-button" (click)="sendBreakdown($event)">Send Detailed Breakdown</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

**finished.component.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-finished',
  templateUrl: './finished.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./finished.component.scss'],
})
export class FinishedComponent implements OnInit {
  data = [
    {
      name: 'Testdata',
      capacity: 11,
      id: this.generateId()
    },
    {
      name: 'Testdata2',
      capacity: 101,
      id: this.generateId()
    }
  ];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendBreakdown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.apiService.sendEmail(this.data).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  private generateId() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
  }

}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  serverUrl = 'myServerUrlHere';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  sendEmail(data: any[]) {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.serverUrl, data);
  }

}
```

Comment: about get the email, are you asking about UserInput or  [(ngModel)] https://angular.io/guide/user-input#user-input ? about the e.preventDefault is the first time in my live I see some like it

Answer (score 1):

Use the following edit to get the email address:

```
    <form class="form-group-submit">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required  placeholder="Enter your Email Address" [(ng-model)]="EmailId">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit-button" (click)=getById(PostId)"">Send Detailed Breakdown</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

This will take care of 2-way model binding to your EmailId. Your ng-click directive will pick up the correct value entered in input element. After you get the data just bind append it with the POST request you are sending.

**For your first problem:**
Add EmailId variable in your .TS file.

```
EmailId : String;
finalData : any;
```

Make you sendBreakdown function like this:

```
sendBreakdown(e) {
finalData = angular.extend(this.data, JSON.stringify({"Email" : this.EmailId}));
this.apiService.sendEmail(this.finaldata).subscribe(
  (response) => console.log(response),
  (error) => console.log(error)
);
```

}